# diacritics signs in url AFNetworking GET

Tags: ios, get, diacritics, afnetworking-2

I have problem which drives me crazy. My API provider has url with diacritics signs e.g:

```
NSString *url = @"http://apiprovideraddress.com/user?param_id=sdn-ło-13/z" // ł - diacritic sign
```

If in url address exists any diacritic sign then "AFNetworking" return in this function `NSParameterAssert` which breaks code:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(id)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error


NSParameterAssert(URLString) //URLString = nil
```

Stack:

```
[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:]

[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager GET:parameters:success:failure:]
```

I'm using this function to "GET":

```
[myManager GET:url parameters:nil success:failure:];
```

If an "url" is without diacritic then everything works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From RFC 3986: When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS], the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent encoded. For example, the character A would be represented as "A", the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE would be represented as "%C3%80", and the character KATAKANA LETTER A would be represented as "%E3%82%A2".

Use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` to encode the URL, it will do the right thing with UTF-8 non-ASCII characters.

Example:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://apiprovideraddress.com/user?param_id=sdn-ło-13/z"; // ł - diacritic sign
NSLog(@"urlString: %@", urlString);
NSString *s = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"s: %@", s);
```

NSLog output:

urlString: http://apiprovideraddress.com/user?param_id=sdn-ło-13/z
s: http://apiprovideraddress.com/user?param_id=sdn-%C5%82o-13/z

Note: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is known to omit some escapes that are optional.

A more conservative answer to this particular URL is:
http%3A%2F%2Fapiprovideraddress.com%2Fuser%3Fparam_id%3Dsdn-%C5%82o-13%2Fz

Answer (score 0):

URIs can only contain ACSII characters.  They may not contain Unicode characters.

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Comment: In the OP case the URL could be encoded as: http%3A%2F%2Fapiprovideraddress.com%2Fuser%3Fparam_id%3Dsdn-%C5%82o-13%2Fz

Comment: You saved my life Zaph! And a lot of aspirin because of headache ;) Thanks! Write your answer as separate post and I will be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Those are the parameters of the requests, you can pass them in the `parameter` parameter, as a NSDictionary

something like

```
@{
   @"param_id" : @"sdn-ło-13/z"
 }
```